# Assign ß on MacBook or external Magic Keyboard to long pressing S

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, shortcut-menu

On Mac OS 10.15.4, when long-pressing keys such as E, O etc., we can chose from a small menu displaying several options for that letter.

I am searching for a possibility to write the letter ß in the same way. I know I can type "option + S", but this is not what I want

*Question:*

**Is there a way to assign ß to an option menu that appears when long pressing the letter S (similar to ling pressing letters such as E, O, U etc.)?**

Thanks a lot!

*Edit after comments*:

- I have a MacBook Pro with a Dutch keyboard layout.
- Language & Region settings: Preferred languages = English (US); Region = United States

Comment: Using **macOS Catalina 10.15.4** set to **US English** under **Language & Region** in **System Preferences**,  if I _long press_ the **S** _key_ I get the pop-up with **ß** on it.

Comment: It's probably quicker to use Opt/s to get ß than wait for the long press.

Comment: @user3439894 's comment is an answer. Works for me on Mojave, too. Perhaps it doesn't work on alternate Keyboard layouts?

Comment: I can confirm that long pressing "s" on the default german MacBook keyboard layout works! Using macOS Catalina 10.15.5 on MBA 2020 - no keyboard layout modifications.

Comment: Please see my edit in the post. My keyboard is Dutch. Pressing S doesn't open any option menu unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest fix is to just switch to the US or ABC input source.  These have the same mapping as Dutch, but with more press/hold options.

If you want to customize the Dutch input source, see [this](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/custom-characters-accent-popup-osx/):